# Can not create unique id for text field using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating multiple text field using button click but I can not create unique id for each field. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="intro-box">
    <input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left;margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname0" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(1);">
  </div>
  <script>
    function addMore(i) {

      $("#plus").remove();

      $('#intro-box').append('<div><input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname' + i + '" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">' +
        '<input type="button" onclick="removeThis(' + i + ');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus' + i + '" value="-" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;"></div>' +
        '<div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(' + (i++) + ');"></div>');
    }

    function removeThis(j) {
      $("#introlabelname" + j).remove();
      $("#minus" + j).remove();
    }
  </script>
```

Initially id is `introlabelname0` while the multiple field will create it should like this `introlabelname1,introlabelname2...` and so on. Similarly while user will click on `-` button the all ids also should come serially like `introlabelname0,introlabelname1,introlabelname2...`.

Here is my total [Plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/2sBTN5WG3lWVeyM6mIKW?p=preview).

Comment: I don't understand why you need that index and indexID at all. P.S: you don't need it, well unless you need unique form action elements names... But I see no form...

Comment: It will help to extract all text field value in a loop easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<script>
    var a = 0;
    function addMore(i) {

        a = a + 1;

        i = a;

        $("#plus").remove();

        $('#intro-box').append('<div><input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname' + i + '" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">' +
        '<input type="button" onclick="removeThis(' + i + ');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus' + i + '" value="-" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;"></div>' +
        '<div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(' + (i++) + ');"></div>');
    }

    function updateIds(){
        var textboxElements = $('#intro-box input:text');

        for(var j = 0; j < textboxElements.length; j++) {
            $('#intro-box input:text')[j].id = "introlabelname" + j;
            console.log($('#intro-box input:text')[j].id);
        }

    }

    function removeThis(j) {
        $("#introlabelname" + j).remove();
        $("#minus" + j).remove();
        updateIds();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @ gkb : But while user is deleting the text box the `ids` of the remaining text-box will come also serially. But here not happening like that.Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Save a variable `total` and use that to know how many inputs you have:

```
var total = 0;
function addMore(i) {
  total++;
  $("#plus").remove();

  $('#intro-box').append('<div><input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname' + total + '" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">' +
    '<input type="button" onclick="removeThis(' + i + ');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus' + i + '" value="-" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;"></div>' +
    '<div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore(' + (i++) + ');"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function generateUID(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 * Date.now());
}
```

and this will return a random number. Use that to construct your element, also using the index of the element is a good point.(But querying for elements every time is resources consuming).

Answer (score 0):

Find answer in [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/JIOHqS5f9PhgU4LdMAAu?p=preview), instead of creating DOM on the fly i cloned it. there are multiple way to achieve  the same

```js
function init() {
            $('input[type=text].form-control ').each(function(i) {
                $(this).removeAttr('id', '').attr('id', 'introlabelname' + i);
            });
            $('.minus').show().last().hide();
            $('.plus').hide().last().show();
        }

        function addMore(i) {
          
          $('.input-wrap').first().clone().appendTo('#intro-box');
            init();

        }
       
        function remove(el){
           $(el).closest('.input-wrap').remove();
            init();
        }
       
        init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello</h1>
    <div class="form-group" id="intro-box">
       
          <div class="input-wrap" style="clear:both">
              <input type="text" style="width:85%;float:left;margin-bottom:5px;" class="form-control" id="introlabelname0" name="introlabelname" placeholder="Label Name" value="">
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm plus"  value="+" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="addMore();">
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm minus"  value="-" style="font-size:21px; line-height:12px; border-radius:4px; margin:3px; margin-bottom:6px;" onclick="remove(this);">
          </div>
        
    </div>
```